# Windows 8.1 Opens a File Explorer Window on Polling External Drives

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive

I just upgraded to Windows 8.1 from 8.0. I have 3 external HDDs. Now when Windows polls the external drives it automatically opens a File Explorer window at the root of the drive. Every time the OS polls for external drives this happens. While not critical by any means it is extremely annoying, to say the least because it goes on throughout the day. Even if I leave the File Explorer windows open they will pop to the foreground when the OS does its polling. The only way to stop this behaviour is to shut down the drives. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here.